# Edit and Continue in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

Edit-And-Continue is one of my favorite debugging tools which I have previously used on C# based Winforms and ASP.NET projects. However, I'm running a Silverlight 3.0 application on VS 2008 and whenever I try to make a change (after breaking) it says "Changes are not allowed when debugging Silverlight applications". Also there isn't an "Enable Edit and Continue" option in the project settings.

Does anyone (possibly an insider) know when this feature will be supported by Microsoft???
(I *NEED* IT!)

Answer (score 8):

I doubt it will ever be a feature, to be honest.  EAC has always required you to attach directly to your .exe in order to work.  In the case of Silverlight, that .exe is the browser, which is not the .exe you are developing.

If you are looking to edit XAML while running, you might consider a dynamic loading situation where you can refresh the control at runtime.  In that case, you can edit XAML while debugging, but I'm afraid you're stuck with the managed code.

**EDIT:**
One possibility that you might consider (but I haven't tried it) is to write your code against unit tests.  Then, there  is a tool called [TestDriven.net](http://testdriven.net/) that allows you to debug your tests with EAC (as an advanced feature).  From there, you **might** be able to do some EAC, but you will be doing it via unit tests, not actually in the Silverlight environment.

Comment: still the case with 4: [However, it does not support edit-and-continue, just-in-time debugging, and mixed-mode debugging.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838267.aspx)